# Iterate over ARRAY, declare temp table. postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor, postgresql-9.3

I am passing a list of ids, I need to iterate over that list and make SELECTIONS.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_things_block 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    unique_thing_block_name VARCHAR(64)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_thing 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    unique_thing_name VARCHAR(64),
    unique_thing_block INTEGER references unique_things_block(id),
    unique_thing_description VARCHAR(256),
    is_boolean boolean NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS permutations 
(
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    unique_thing_id INTEGER references unique_thing(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(id, unique_thing_id)

);


INSERT INTO unique_thing 
VALUES(1, 'dgsg', 1, 'It means that blablabla...', FALSE);

INSERT INTO unique_thing 
VALUES(2, 'dfgdfg', 1, 'Too long text...', FALSE);

INSERT INTO unique_thing 
VALUES(3, 'sdf wdfs', 2, 'It means that blablabla...', FALSE);

INSERT INTO unique_thing 
VALUES(4, 'sdf fdg fdg', 2, 'Too long text...', FALSE);

INSERT INTO unique_thing 
VALUES(5, 'dfg dfg', 2, 'dfg Too long text...', FALSE);

INSERT INTO unique_thing 
VALUES(6, 'dfg dfg', 2, 'df Too long text...', FALSE);

INSERT INTO unique_thing 
VALUES(7, 'dfg', 3, 'How to make...', TRUE);

INSERT INTO unique_thing 
VALUES(8, 'dfg', 3, 'asdasdsd...', TRUE);

INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(1, 7);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(2, 1);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(2, 3);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(2, 8);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(3, 1);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(3, 4);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(3, 7);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(4, 1);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(4, 4);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(4, 8);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(5, 1);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(5, 5);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(5, 7);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(6, 1);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(6, 5);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(6, 8);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(7, 1);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(7, 6);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(7, 7);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(8, 1);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(8, 6);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(8, 8);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(9, 2);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(9, 3);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(9, 7);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(10, 2);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(10, 3);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(10, 8);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(11, 2);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(11, 4);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(11, 7);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(12, 2);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(12, 4);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(12, 8);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(13, 2);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(13, 5);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(13, 7);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(14, 2);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(14, 5);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(14, 8);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(15, 2);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(15, 6);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(15, 7);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(16, 2);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(16, 6);
INSERT INTO permutations VALUES(16, 8);
```

But could you please help to do it? In mysql we can just create a cursor (CREATE temporary table) and insert into it.

How but can I do it in posgresql? I will run it as

```
SELECT * FROM get_things_by_id(ARRAY[1,3]);

DROP function get_things_by_id(ids integer[]);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_things_by_id(ids integer[])
  RETURNS table(pr INTEGER, cons INTEGER) AS $$
BEGIN

CREATE TEMP TABLE found_items ON COMMIT DROP AS(
  id INTEGER
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE found_unique_things ON COMMIT DROP AS(
  id INTEGER
);

DECLARE
  temp_result found_items;

DECLARE
  temp_result_found_unique_things found_unique_things;

SELECT id INTO temp_result FROM ids;

for i in temp_result:
    SELECT id INTO temp_result_found_unique_things FROM permutations where  
    WHERE unique_thing_id = $0') using i;

for g in temp_result_found_unique_things:
    make another selections


END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I've created this function, but it shows me the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "problem_id"
LINE 6:   problem_id INTEGER,
```

I do not understand why it happens because there is no detailed info about the error.

Comment: the other strange - your example doesn't contains "problem_id". When I have

Answer (score 1):

The code is pretty messy.

- The PostgreSQL plpgsql function have to have syntax described in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html).
- Cycle `FOR i IN temp_result:` looks like Python cycle, not like PLpgSQL [cycle](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).
- Creating temporary tables cannot be in `DECLARE` part of function body. These statements should in function body (after `BEGIN` keyword).
- The arrays and tables in Postgres are different objects, you cannot to mix them.
- Don't use compose variables for single field values - it is slower.
- Clause `USING` should be used on in `EXECUTE` statement.

It is looking, so you want to iterate over array

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(ids int[])
RETURNS TABLE(...) AS $$
DECLARE
   i int;
   temp_result_id int;
BEGIN
  FOREACH i IN ARRAY ids
  LOOP
    SELECT id INTO temp_result_id FROM permutations
      WHERE unique_thing_id = i;
    ...
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

There is big rule - **What can be done with SQL, should be done with SQL.**. For this case, you don't need a iteration over array - just use `=ANY` operator and reduce number of nested cycles:

```
SELECT .. FROM tab WHERE unique_thing_id = ANY(ids)
```

Comment: I think I have explained it incorrectly. ANY return a lot of row, it's wrong here. When I find ARRAY[1,3,7], the function must return only one row, because it happens  for the only  id  1. There is the only case in permutations table: row 1 3, row 1 1,  row 1 7. The first value is id. So,1 3, 7 is for id 1 only